# Python+Pillow opens an EMF image file incorrectly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have faced the problem that Python+Pillow opened an EMF image file incorrectly.

First, I write a formula with Office Math in a MS-Word document.

Second, I run VBA code to create an EMF image file.

```
(VBA code)
Set equation = ActiveDocument.OMaths(1)
quation.Range.Select
Selection.Cut
Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

Third, I run Python code ("zipfile") to pick up the EMF image file from the Word file and then open it with Pillow.

```
(Python code)
for file in zipped_files:
    if file.startswith(image_folder):
        img_file = docx_zip.open(file)
        img_bytes = img_file.read()
        img_path = img_dir / Path(file).name
        with img_path.open(mode="wb") as f3:
            f3.write(img_bytes)
        img_file.close()
*snip*
img = Image.open("image1.emf")
img.show()
```

For some reason, the formula displayed is shrunk in a width direction by about 30% to 70%.

My PC environment is:
Windows 11
Word 2019
Python 3.11.1
Pillow 9.5.0

Other Viewers (Irfan View, MS-Paint, etc), however, can open the EMF image file, which is picked up from the MS-Word document, correctly without shrinking it.

What should I do to display an EMF image file correctly with Python+Pillow?

If anyone knows, please let me know.
thank you.

Comment: My suggestion would be to share the EMF file so we can deduce whether it is your export from MS Office that is at fault, or the import into PIL. You can use Google Drive or similar to share documents that `imgur` doesn't like.